# Add button on Homepage - WordPress Custom Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a website with WordPress custom theme.
Is there any guide how to add a custom button/image on the left side of homepage?
Something eye-catching.

Comment: How much you are good with css. I can give you the html code in footer section you need to set that html button on left side with doing css

Comment: Thanks for your help, where do i have to place this code? If i want to show this only on specific pages for example en_en/index.php

Comment: functions.php of active theme

Comment: It adds on <head> <div class="button"><a href="htttp://www.google.com">Your Button</a></div> but nothing appears on frontend

Comment: try with below code and check in footer section

Comment: with wp_footer nothing on front-end or source

Comment: did you check with view page source? it must be there before body ends

Comment: yeap nothing there

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: This question is off topic: See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting. **Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
add_action('wp_footer','placingButton');
function placingButton()
{
  if ( is_front_page() ) {    
    echo '<div class="button"><a href="#">Your button</a></div>';
  }   
}
```